# Data undefined after refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I have an issue with my react and express/mongodb app where the first load `miscData` is not defined (which is the name of my collection in my mongodb database), but when I comment out all the paragraph tags and only `console.log(getBasic)` I am able to log it (when before I was unable to log it due to it being undefined) and then when I uncomment the paragraph tags I am able to see them now, that is until I refresh which resets this.

I have a console.log statement and then 3 html paragraphs that display the blogTitles. When I first boot it doesn't work until I do the comment save, uncomment save, refresh method mentioned above.

Here is a 1 minute [video](https://youtu.be/pfECy6HHO-A) that shows what I am talking about if that didn't make much sense.

App.js:

```
function App() {

  const [getBasic, setGetBasic] = useState()

  async function fetchData() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
    .then(result => setGetBasic(result.data))

    
  }



  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <p>{JSON.stringify(getBasic.miscData[1].blogTitle)}</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(getBasic.miscData[2].blogTitle)}</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(getBasic.miscData[3].blogTitle)}</p>
      {console.log(`getBasic ${JSON.stringify(getBasic)}`)}

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  db.collection('miscData').find().toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      res.send({ miscData: result })
  })
})
```

This is what `miscData` looks like:

```
getBasic {"miscData":[{"_id":"62604421b57b621bda4171c7","blogTitle":"Different title","blogBody":"lorem ipsum etc etc etc"},{"_id":"626058bb61967575695bdade","blogTitle":"Com squadron","blogBody":"asidjaoisdoasodjiaosjdoia"},{"_id":"626059f961967575695bdadf","blogTitle":"test","blogBody":"test"},{"_id":"62605a3d36e02b8581f56154","blogTitle":"asdasda","blogBody":"adadada"},{"_id":"62608bc60bd6de526fd1b0bc","blogTitle":"new title","blogBody":"new body"}]}
```

My React is port 3000, and server is 3001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the method `fetchData()` is an asynchronous call, i.e., the term asynchronous refers to two or more objects or events not existing or happening at the same time (or multiple related things happening without waiting for the previous one to complete) [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Asynchronous).

Whereas the `<p>` tags are synchronous code, they render even before your data is fetched from the backend. Hence you receive undefined for a while and as soon as it is fetched, the `<p>` tags get populated and you can see them. This also explains why it resets when you refresh it.

Comment: what would be the easiest way to fix this? How can I render the react components only after the data is fetched?

Comment: You can do that using React conditional rendering. Checkout the docs : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Hello OP, got a lil busy but here's an example how you could do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-butterfly-ehnmdy?file=/src/App.js. I have used `Skeleton` from `Material-UI` as a loading alternative and since my API is too fast I have put a delay using `setTimeout` , feel free to skip, rest is similar to your code. Upvote if it helped :))